# Laravel how to see executed queries from terminal

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel PHP framework. Is there any way to see executed queries from terminal. The default log file only giving me exception error. I also tried with profiler which give the queries in the browser but I want to see it from terminal.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131731/laravel-4-logging-sql-queries/19193395#19193395

Answer (score 2):

You can add this to your app/start/global.php:

```
DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time) { 
    Log::info($sql);
});
```

And then they will automatically appear in your log file.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 3 the profiler can be enabled to true at application/config/application.php and application/config/database.php. You will get a query log in the bottom of the page.

In Laravel 4, the DB::getQueryLog() can be used.