# Laravel 4 : How to display SQL queries ran?

Tags: php, logging, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

In my app/config/app.php file, I have turned on `'debug'=>true`.
I have tried

```
//run eloquent functions
$allMessages = Messages::with('User')->whereIn('conv_id',$conv_id)->orderBy('created_at','aadesc')->take(10);

$q= DB::getQueryLog();
dd($q);
```

but it returns an empty array. So I guess it is useless to do `end($q)` as suggested.

I have also tried the accepted [answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131731/laravel-4-logging-sql-queries#answer-19193395) and added it to the end of my routes file but nothing happened. I'm still new to Laravel and need some guidance. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A popular method is to monitor the Event for Eloquent, and output any queries run on the database as you are going along:

```
Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query, $params, $time, $conn) 
{ 
    dd(array($query, $params, $time, $conn));
});

$allMessages = Messages::with('User')->whereIn('conv_id',$conv_id)->orderBy('created_at','aadesc')->take(10);
```

That will output the query that is run.

Another option is to use a Laravel4 Debugger package, which automatically shows you the queries run: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar