# Issue with simple data base query code in PhP

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PhP. I got a code from some other team member and just trying to make a minor change.

The code is to get a list of items from DB. It uses "where" clause to compare industry parameter with the industry input parameter in sql query. This code works fine. I just want to replace "=" with "LIKE" comparison for the query->where clause.

Here is the current code with "=" which works

```
 public function feed($industry=null){
    $query = DB::table('startups as s')
    ->leftjoin('founders as fd','fd.startup_id','=','s.id');
    if($industry)
        $query->where('s.industry','=',$industry);      
    $result = $query->select('s.id as sid','fd.name as fdname','fd.email','fd.contact','s.*','s.created_at',DB::raw("(select sum(f.fund_amount) from funds as f where f.startup_id=s.id and f.fund_amount>0)as 'total'"))
    ->groupBy('s.id')
    ->get();
    return json_encode($result);        
},
```

Below is one of my multiple attempts to replace "=" with LIKE (but so far no option has worked - seem simple but again haven't worked in PhP so I am missing something)

```
 public function feed($industry=null){
    $industryFilter = "%{$industry}%";
    $query = DB::table('startups as s')
    ->leftjoin('founders as fd','fd.startup_id','=','s.id');
    if($industry)
        $query->where('s.industry','LIKE',$industryFilter);     
    $result = $query->select('s.id as sid','fd.name as fdname','fd.email','fd.contact','s.*','s.created_at',DB::raw("(select sum(f.fund_amount) from funds as f where f.startup_id=s.id and f.fund_amount>0)as 'total'"))
    ->groupBy('s.id')
    ->get();
    return json_encode($result);        
},
```

Comment: Look into the `DB` class and its documentation for clues. It doesn't seem to be part of PHP itself. If it's a freely available library, I suggest you post name and version of it here.

Comment: Just as a random guess, try putting spaces either side of `' LIKE '`.

Comment: Adding space didn't help.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast - not sure but I think it's laravel framework as I have seen documentation - https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: laravel - laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've amended the where clause correctly but just try this:

```
public function feed($industry=null){

    $query = DB::table('startups as s')
        ->leftjoin('founders as fd','fd.startup_id','=','s.id');
    if( $industry ){
        $query->where('s.industry','LIKE', '%'.$industry.'%');     
    }

    $result = $query->select('s.id as sid','fd.name as fdname','fd.email','fd.contact','s.*','s.created_at',DB::raw("(select sum(f.fund_amount) from funds as f where f.startup_id=s.id and f.fund_amount > 0)as 'total'"))
        ->groupBy('s.id')
        ->get();

    return json_encode($result);        
}
```

Hopefully that works and helps

Comment: Tried this earlier and tried again but didn't fix it...Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: if you log the db query being executed as per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131731/laravel-4-logging-sql-queries) thread what is actually being run?